# Using "C" function and variables in "C++" code

Tags: c++, c

I need to call "C" function which is having one argument variable `"struct"` (which is defined in "C" file), from "C++" file.

I used `'extern "C"'`, but getting linking error.

Please suggest me some way to do it ?

Thanks
Priyanshu

Comment: Can you post what you have tried thus far?

Comment: "extern C" should be used in CPP file which declaring that function

Comment: @Alexander Rafferty: No, it's not.  C++ is *mostly* a superset of C, but it is not a strict superset. (As a trivial example, a C program that uses variable names that conflict with C++-specific keywords obviously is not legal C++ code.) And that doesn't say much about linking compatibilities anyway.

Comment: @Alexander Rafferty: If you mean most of the language, okay.  If you mean most C source files, I disagree.  Well-written C code often is not valid C++.  For example, in C it's usually recommended not to cast the return value of `malloc`, but C++ disallows implicit casts from `void*`.

Comment: Yes, I did mean most of the language. Most C can be modified to fit C++ standards, unless there is far to much source code to rake through.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have not come back, here is a possible file arrangement and header file you *probably* should be looking at.

// Here is Header file (myh.h)

```
struct S{};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void fn(S s);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

// Here is CPP file (ZCPP.cpp)

```
#include "myh.h"

int main(){
   S s;
   fn(s);
}
```

// Here is C file (ZC.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myh.h"

void fn(S s){
   printf("Hi\n");
}
```

> [prompt@test ~]$ g++ zcpp.cpp zc.c
>
> [prompt@test ~]$ ./a.out
>
> Hi
>
> [prompt@test ~]$

Answer (score 0):

You should read this thread [**How to mix C and C++**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) for understanding the ins and outs of mixing C and C++ code.

When done, you can also have a look at the corresponding [**FQA thread**](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/mixing.html).